# How can I assign to the ipython global namespace from within ipdb?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdb, ipdb

I have a traceback in an IPython notebook that I'm debugging with the `%debug` magic. I'd like to assign one of the objects in the traceback frame to a variable in the IPython global namespace, so that I can mess with it outside the `ipdb` prompt (which is rather clunky). What's the easiest way to do this?

I solved this for now by pickling the object in ipdb and unpickling it from the global namespace, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to assign the value to a *module-member* (something like a global var in module's scope), which persists after you quit the `pdb` session, since the module is already in `sys.modules`, and stays there.

```
1% os.path.exists(3254)
...
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

2% %debug
...
ipdb> os.MYVAR = 234
ipdb> q

3% os.MYVAR
3= 234
```

Comment: Ah! I can assign to the ipython global namespace using `sys.modules['__main__'].foo = 1`. Thanks!